Can I replace Shimano Deodore SL-M511 with SL-M590 or SL-M510?
I am new to this and have purchased a bike that has damaged (broken) the left shifter. Can I replace this by purchasing a Shimano Deodore SL-M570 or SL-M510. Are these compatible?

Yes, these are all 9 speed shifters, so are compatible with each other.
